# error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.yarnpkg.com registry.yarnpkg.com:443"

Tags: reactjs

yarn add v1.3.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.yarnpkg.com registry.yarnpkg.com:443".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/shiv/my-app/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar error and it succeeded when I ran the command again. I think it was just due to a slow internet connection and something timing out.

Answer (score 4):

I had same error while instaling jquery package.
The problem disapeared, after I disabled my VPN network .

Comment: Yes, VPN may terminate yarn connection attempts. It was helpfull.

Comment: nice, thanks a lot, this worked

Answer (score 4):

I jus had to restart my pc to fix it

Answer (score 1):

For me, I just had to disconnect and reconnect my WiFi to fix this.